# Parse simple JSON into dataframe with R

Tags: r, json

A seemingly simple JSON file that I would like to parse with R:

```r
tmp_extract <- "{\"encrypted_values\":[{\"name_a\":\"value_a\"}, {\"name_b\":\"value_b\"}, {\"name_c\":\"value_c\"}]}"
```

An attempt with `jsonlite::fromJSON` produces a dataframe with as many columns as there are names and only a value per column.

```
tmp_extract |> 
 jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

```
$encrypted_values
   name_a  name_b  name_c
1 value_a    <NA>    <NA>
2    <NA> value_b    <NA>
3    <NA>    <NA> value_c
```

(I also tried `tmp_extract |> tidyjson::spread_all()` but without success.)

The desired output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name   value  
  <chr>  <chr>  
1 name_a value_a
2 name_b value_b
3 name_c value_c
```

Comment: The data seems correctly extracted for the format you have in the JSON.
I believe that you probably want to extract a JSON that looks like this:
```"{\"encrypted_values\":[{\"name_a\":\"value_a\", \"name_b\":\"value_b\", \"name_c\":\"value_c\"}]}"```

Comment: Can you show what your desired output is?

Comment: Just added the desired output to the question.

Comment: The JSON file has 7000+ elements if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```r
tibble::enframe(unlist(unname(jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp_extract, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE))))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   name   value  
#   <chr>  <chr>  
# 1 name_a value_a
# 2 name_b value_b
# 3 name_c value_c
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the CRAN package [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons) and [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query syntax, create in JSON an object with fields name and value

```
query <- '{
    name: encrypted_values[].keys(@)[],
    value: encrypted_values[].values(@)[]
}'
## check out our handiwork
j_query(tmp_extract, query) |> cat("\n")
# {"name":["name_a","name_b","name_c"],"value":["value_a","value_b","value_c"]}
```

then 'pivot' to a tibble (or data.frame)

```
j_pivot(tmp_extract, query, as = "tibble")
```

This approach is performant and flexible; it can be applied to NDJSON  too.